# Chromecast to multiple devices

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromecast

I'm building a web application and I need to cast some media (photos and maybe videos) to multiple TV sets. So far not too bad, I've managed to build my sender application that sends to a chromecast device and then after looking into others I learned I can use different instances of chrome profiles to even broadcast to multiple TV sets at once and that's also done.

Here are my questions and issues at this time.
1) As far as I know there is no way to bypass the user popup that selects a device for broadcasting and I kind of understand the logic however it would really be the best if somehow this could be by passed. I don't have to use chrome and html code and if this means I need to write in Java or use other platforms it's fine. What I hope is to be able to select the device via my code instead of via user popup from the extension. Even if we need some sort of one time authentication I understand but the issue is as it stands today, anytime I restart my browser I have to go over the selection process. In my case this suppose to be an unattended application and having this user required step is really a huge issue.
2) I like to know if I can broadcast to multiple devices within the same html page or application. Again at this time my understanding is a single session can be established at any given time with a single chromecase device under a single user profile. My requirement calls for broadcasting to multiple devices at the same time from the same application/page. Any way I can do this within a single profile?

Any help or pointers is very much appreciated.

Amir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to bypass the popup; that is the model we would like to follow. As for broadcasting to multiple devices, that is not supported either.

Comment: Disappointing but good to know. Don't understand the downvote either.

Comment: I don't downvote questions, wasn't me and I don't understand it either.

Comment: How is broadcasting to multiple devices not supported? From my understand as long as the sender app handles multiple sessions you are able to broadcast to multiple device from a single page.

Comment: Do you have any working examples? All I've seen suggests Ali's answer is correct, the only solution I've seen and used is to setup multiple profiles. If you can provide a working example it would be very helpful.

Comment: As far as I can see, your POC doesn't work; have you tried it? How does it get the second session?

Comment: The POC should work. In the sender, there are two variables ('session' and 'session2') that maintain two unique sessions. Each session has its own set of handler functions. Have a look through the sender code and you'll see that there is nothing magical happening. The second session is created and maintained through a set of functions and elements that parallel the originals; that is all. It is fairly straight-forward to generalize the idea behind the sender to a more robust solution that does not rely on hardcoding each session and does not have a separate set of functions for each session.

Comment: How is the second session established? The first one is established when you select a device and a callback from SDK establishes that. How are you selecting the second route? Who establishes that? Just because you create a variable "session2" similar to the first one doesn't do anything. Who is calling sessionListener2? As soon as you select the first device, the cast button doesn't even let you "add" another one.

Comment: There is an `update2()` function that is called when the second form is submitted. `update2()` then gets the value contained in `input2` and passes it along to `sendMessage2()`. `sendMessage2()` then checks if `session2` is already established. If it is, it sends the message to the receiver. If it isn't, it requests a new session which is then assigned to `session2` and is used to send a message to a second device if you want. When the Google Cast options show up, if you have multiple devices attached, you should be able to choose to go back to the list of Chromecasts and select any of them.

Comment: I'd like to know if there is a way to allow casting to multiple devices (more then 2, so it needs to be dynamic). Why isn't this supported by default, and has anyone found a solution for Chrome?